# Override all properties of an element and its children

Tags: html, css, angular-material

I am using the `md-menu` element from [angular material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/menu) in a project. Due to certain circumstances, the properties of said element are being changed in a global file that I do need. Is there any way to quickly do a sort of global override on my element? My code is virtually identical to the example linked.

Comment: Can you post your code/css or create an example?

Comment: Something like [this](http://codepen.io/vladdobra/pen/rWVLpd?editors=1100), just with roughly a hundred more properties added to it. Making seperate classes for each element that uses the modified code is not preferable, since the code is used throughout the project. Also, the properties added to the md-menu are not as superficial as just a border or something, the padding and margins are fundamentally changed.